# Why doesn't n choose k work for selecting a 3-committee form 6 people?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, problem-solving

We have 6 people, A,B,C,D,E,F in a committee and we're to select a chair, secretary and a treasurer. In how many ways can this be done?

My initial attempt was: Ok easy, we just count how many ways we can select 3 people from 6, since obviously, we will assign these three selected people to the different roles, and we don't care about the order. Sounds simple right? Just $C(6,3)$.

That's wrong however and I yet again don't undersand why. (I understand why it's $6\times5\times4$ but why not $C(6,3)$?)

Comment: Well, say you choose the unordered set $\{A,B,C\}$.  Which one is the chair?

Comment: One of A, B or C. We don't know, maybe that's the problem of the C(6,3) approach?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.  You weren't asked to choose an unordered collection, you were asked to choose an ordered collection.  To fix your computation, just multiply by the number of ways to order three elements, namely $3!=6$

Comment: I see. Committees are ordered since the roles must be assignable to someone.

Comment: Right.  If you had only $3$ people, the answer would be $6$, not $\binom 33=1$.  Your answer would be correct if you were asked "how many three person committees can you form out of six people?"

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is almost correct. However, once the three people are chosen in ${6 \choose 3}$ ways, they need to be assigned 3 different roles. This can be done in $3!$ ways. Thus, the final answer comes to ${6\choose3}3!=120$